# Floating point to fixed point conversion

Tags: matlab

I am working on floating point to fixed point theory in Matlab. I just need to convert a negative decimal number into binary string but dec2bin command is not working. Kindly suggest me some solution.

please see the following code

```
      freq=-7.2722e-005
      u_frac=25
      u_fi0=freq*2^u_frac
      u_fi=round(u_fi0)
      u_fi_b= dec2bin(u_fi0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 32-bit signed integer, you have to add 2^32 to ever negative number:

```
dec2bin(u_fi0+2^32)
```

The result is:

```
11111111111111111111011001110111
```

Comment: Sir why it is so? How I can Identify the bits?

Comment: 2^32-x unsigned integer and -x signed integer have the same bit representation. For more details take a look at the way negative integers are stored, e.g. wikipedia `Two's complement`